# Key pressing special characters using Robot class Java

Tags: java, special-characters, awtrobot

I am writing a program that simply retypes the text from the data file. The program works until it hits its first special character. Here is an example:

**data file**

`Hey what is up?`

**what i get**

`Hey what is up (throws illegal argument exception)`

Here is my code:

```
 public static void KeyPresser() throws FileNotFoundException, AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("script.dat"));
        while(file.hasNext()) {
            String word = file.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0;i<word.length();i++) {
                char c = word.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                }

                robot.keyPress(Character.toUpperCase(c));
                robot.keyRelease(Character.toUpperCase(c));

                if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                }
               if(c=='?') {
                   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
                   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
                   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
               }

            }

    }

        }
```

It types up the letters, but not the special characters? Am I gonna have to use a long switch code? Or is there an easy fix to this? As you can tell I have tried using

```
                  if(c=='?') {
                   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
                   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
                   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); 
}
```

But that doesnt work, what can i do?

Comment: Which line is actually throwing the exception?

Comment: You need to check for the special characters first. If you find one you invoke the code and then break the loop so you can process the next character in the file.

Comment: I didn't have any issues with the key sequence, but what OS are running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am writing a program that simply retypes the text from the data file

Why are you using a Robot to retype the text? Why can't you just insert the text into a document of your text component.

> Am I gonna have to use a long switch code?

You can use a HashMap to map a key that needs to be shifted with the regular key:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RobotString extends JPanel
{
    private static HashMap<Character, Character> keyMap = new HashMap<>();

    private JTextField original;
    private JTextField copy;


    public RobotString()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        original = new JTextField(10);
        add(original, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JButton button = new JButton("Use Robot");
        add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        button.addActionListener((e) -> invokeRobot() );

        copy = new JTextField(10);
        add(copy, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //  Create mapping of keys

        keyMap.put('!', '1');
        keyMap.put('@', '2');
        keyMap.put('#', '3');
        keyMap.put(':', ';');
        keyMap.put('?', '/');
    }

    private void invokeRobot()
    {
        copy.requestFocusInWindow();
        copy.setText( "" );

        try
        {
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            char[] letters = original.getText().toCharArray();

            for(char letter: letters)
            {
                boolean shiftRequired = false;
                Character value = keyMap.get(letter);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    shiftRequired = true;
                    letter = value;
                }
                else if (Character.isUpperCase(letter))
                {
                    shiftRequired = true;
                }

                int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar( letter );

                if (shiftRequired)
                    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

                robot.keyPress( keyCode );
                robot.keyRelease( keyCode );

                if (shiftRequired)
                    robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new RobotString());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Just type a text string in the top text field and click the button. Note it only supports a few special characters.
But note this is not a reliable solution because the mapping depends on the keyboard.

I know of now way to provide a generic solution for all keyboards.